# set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS once in parent directory and have it valid in child directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a directory structure with CMakeLists.txt files as follows:

```
Parent_DIR/CMakeLists.txt
Parent_DIR/src/CMakeLists.txt
Parent_DIR/test/CMakeLists.txt
```

I also have a preprocessor variable DOUBLE_PRECISION that controls whether all my calculations are done with doubles or floats. I've been told I need to set the variable in each folder individually, either with

```
set(DOUBLE_PRECISION 1)
```

or

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DDOUBLE_PRECISION")
```

My question is this: Is there any way to set this variable once in the parent directory instead of having to set it in every CMakeLists.txt file? It seems error prone to have to manually set it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` add the CMake command [add_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_definitions)

```
add_definitions(-DDOUBLE_PRECISION)
```

to your `Parent_DIR/CMakeLists.txt` before entering the sub directories with `add_subdirectory`. The command adds preprocessor definitions to the compiler command line for sources in the current directory and below.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable in the cache, it will be set for the whole project, in child directories and in parent directories as well. Add `CACHE` to your `set` command.